# Create multi-key JSON object with integers or floats as values

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a table of text and double precision type. From it, I want to build a JSON object that looks like this: `{"a": 1.0, "b": 1.2, "c": 3.4}` (edit: to clarify, the keys are the text column in my table, and the values are the double precision column). Note that there are no quotes around the values because they are floats, not strings, which the JSON standard supports.

Using Postgres 9.5. There's the `json_build_object` function that takes two parallel text arrays and builds a JSON object with text keys and text values... also works with NULL values, turning them into `null` (no quotes) in JSON. So I'd get `{"a": "1.0", "b": "1.2", "c": "3.4"}`. But what if I want integer or float values? It won't take any numeric type arrays.

I got around it for now by making my own function to handle this in Python! Is there a way to do this without defining a new function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_build_object_float_values(keys TEXT[], vals DOUBLE PRECISION[]) RETURNS JSONB AS
$$
    assert len(keys) == len(vals)
    import json
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        d[keys[i]] = float(vals[i])
    return json.dumps(d)
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpython3u' IMMUTABLE;
```

(note if you use this, it returns JSONB, but you could change it to JSON)

Edit, here's test input and expected output:

```
CREATE TABLE test (str text, num double precision);
INSERT INTO test(str, num) VALUES ('a', 1.0);
INSERT INTO test(str, num) VALUES ('b', 2.3);
-- Here's my solution using my custom function...
SELECT json_build_object_float_values(array_agg(str), array_agg(num)) FROM test;
-- expected output: 
--  json_build_object_float_values
-- --------------------------------
--  {"a": 1.0, "b": 2.3}
-- (1 row)
```

Simpler one:

```
SELECT json_build_object_float_values(ARRAY['the', 'quick'], ARRAY[1, 3]);

 json_build_object_float_values
--------------------------------
 {"the": 1.0, "quick": 3.0}
(1 row)
```

Comment: `json_build_object` looked promising, but it takes a variadic parameter list, not two arrays. Not sure if I can use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

According to your sample data and desired result you can get it using [json_object_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) Postgres function.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (str text, num double precision);
> INSERT INTO test(str, num) VALUES ('a', 1.0);
> INSERT INTO test(str, num) VALUES ('b', 2.3);
> ```

> ```
> select json_object_agg(str, num)
> from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | json_object_agg        |
> | :--------------------- |
> | { "a" : 1, "b" : 2.3 } |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fc6debdc111e6833af17ed5ea680137d)*

You can use [row_to_json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) Postgres function.

> ```
> create table foo(f1 int, f2 varchar(10), f3 float, f4 decimal(18,2));
> insert into foo values (2, 'name', 2.345, 23.23);
> ```

> ```
> select row_to_json(f)
> from   (select f1,f2,f3,f4 from foo) f;
> ```
>
> ```
> | row_to_json                                |
> | :----------------------------------------- |
> | {"f1":2,"f2":"name","f3":2.345,"f4":23.23} |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=91d2fffb4dd9fa972a673f1fbff7920e)*